# When to use IDXGIFactory3::GetCreationFlags

Tags: directx, directx-11, dxgi

i found not much sample programs use IDXGIFactory3, and its function GetCreationFlags, so when to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really only a single defined creation flag, `DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG`, so there's not a lot of value in most programs using this method. It's there as a method for someone to determine if the debug version of DXGI is active or not...

See [DXGI Debug Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/07/27/dxgi-debug-device/)